# Win32::GuiTest - simulate Windows+E to start explorer

Tags: perl, gui-testing

I am using `Win32::GuiTest` to automate some processes. When I needed to open the file explorer using `Windows+E`, I first tried `SendKeys('{LWI}e');`, `SendKeys('{LWI}+e');` and `SendKeys('{LWI}(e)');` yet without it doing what I wanted.

I *was able* to get what I needed with

```
SendRawKey(VK_LWIN , 0);
SendRawKey(ord('E'), 0);

SendRawKey(ord('E'), KEYEVENTF_KEYUP);
SendRawKey(VK_LWIN , KEYEVENTF_KEYUP);
```

Yet, I wondered if there is a less verbose way to achieve the same goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting. I am not sure if there is any shorter way to do it, but, if all you want is an Explorer window, it might be sufficient to just use:

```
system start => 'explorer';
```